# Calcular quantidade de incrementos para que 2 números se tornem iguais

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

**O problema:**

> Com um nome muito criativo, o Protagonista está em seu primeiro
> episódio de sua incrível saga!
>
> Em uma tarde qualquer Z, o melhor amigo do Protagonista, desafiou o
> mesmo para um desafio super divertido.
>
> Z escreve dois números inteiros A e B em um quadro branco e pergunta
> se o Protagonista pode fazer com que os dois inteiros se tornem iguais
> usando o número mínimo de movimentos.
>
> Em um movimento, o Protagonista pode fazer uma das seguintes ações:
>
> 1. Escolher um dos números e adicionar 3 a ele (x = x + 3).
> 2. Escolher um dos números e adicionar 2 a ele (x = x + 2).
>
> Sabendo disso, como o Protagonista sabe que você é muito bom ele pediu
> para que você ajudasse ele nessa missão e o dissesse qual a quantidade
> minima de movimentos que ele precisa para fazer com que os dois
> números se tornem iguais. Você recebe dois inteiros (1 <= A, B <=
> 10^5).  Deve ser impresso um único inteiro N, equivalente a quantidade
> minima de movimentos que o Protagonista precisa para fazer.

**Minha tentativa:**
A entrada ali é padrão da questão pois ele informa os dois números na mesma linha, eu criei uma lista já adicionando eles convertidos pra inteiros pq eles anteriormente eram strings.
Usei a função `max()` e `min()` pra pegar os respectivos valores (maior e menor).
As variáveis estão nomeadas assim pois ainda estava testando, `c1` e `c2` são os contadores dos movimentos de soma que eu faço no menor número, `a` e `b` são duas variáveis temporárias que eu criei pra pegar o valor do menor número.

Depois eu tento criar uma lista de números pulando de 2/3 até chegar no maior número, incrementando o contador a cada repetição.
No final eu comparo qual contador é menor, pois seria a resposta final, o primeiro if, ficou assim pois em alguns casos o contador de ambos ficava igual ex: quando a entrada era 6 e 8.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
entrada = str(input()).split()

numeros = []

for i in entrada:
    numeros.append(int(i))

B = max(numeros)
A = min(numeros)
 
div, mod = divmod(B-A, 3)
if mod != 0:
    div += 3 - mod
 
print(f'{div}')
```

Comment: Poderia descrever em texto qual foi a lógica que tentou implementar?

Comment: Com calma, que não esta dando para entender. Você recebe dois números, no menor você vai o somando de três em três, no maior você vai somando de dois em dois. Você quer saber quantas somas serão necessárias para que os valores sejam iguais?

Comment: Você pode colocar tudo isso direto na pergunta ao [edit]. Melhor que deixar isso nos comentários.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, vou receber dois números, pelo que eu entendi um maior e um menor. o personagem da questão tem duas opções: somar 3 ao número ou somar 2 ao número até eles ficarem iguais (maior e menor número da entrada)

Comment: @Woss tudo bem.

Comment: @AugustoVasques depois eu tenho que dizer qual é o menor movimento que eu faço pra igualar os número (usando 3 ou 2)

Comment: Agora ficou claro, vou só mexer um pouco para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Aproveitando, `input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é desnecessário. E se você já tem certeza absoluta que sempre serão 2 números na mesma linha, pode fazer direto: `a, b = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: João, reverti sua última edição porque é importante que a pergunta tenha o código que vc tentou. Saiba mais em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/112052

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/492507/112052) (que como o próprio autor reconheceu, em alguns casos pode falhar), segue um pequeno ajuste.

A ideia continua a mesma: pegamos a diferença entre os números e dividimos por 3 (vamos chamar o resultado desta divisão de `n`).

Se a divisão for exata (ou seja, se o resto for zero), isso quer dizer que `a` está a exatamente `n` incrementos de 3 de `b`. Até aqui, está igual ao raciocínio da outra resposta.

Se o resto da divisão for 2, então basta fazer mais um incremento de 2 (ou seja, continua igual à outra resposta):

```
a  | a + 3 | a + 6 ... | a + 3n |   2   b
   <---------------------------->   ^
        n incrementos de 3          |
                                    \_ 1 incremento de 2

Total: n + 1 incrementos
```

---

Mas e se o resto da divisão for 1? Isso quer dizer que temos o seguinte:

```
a  | a + 3 | a + 6 ... | a + 3n |   1   b
   <---------------------------->
        n incrementos de 3        + 1
```

A princípio, bastaria mais um incremento de 3 em `a` e um incremento de 2 em `b` (que foi o sugerido na outra resposta), totalizando `n + 2` incrementos. Mas na verdade dá para fazer assim:

- em vez de `n` incrementos de 3, fazemos `n - 1` incrementos de 3. Com isso, ainda faltará 4 para chegar a `b`
- em seguida, fazemos 2 incrementos de 2

```
a  | a + 3 | a + 6 ... | a + 3(n - 1) |   4     b
   <---------------------------------->   ^
        n - 1 incrementos de 3            |
                                          \_  2 incrementos de 2, totalizando os 4 que faltam

Total: n + 1 incrementos
```

No total, teremos `n - 1` incrementos de 3, e 2 incrementos de 2, totalizando `n + 1` incrementos.

---

Ou seja, no fundo tudo se resumiria a:

- divide `b - a` por 3
- se a divisão for exata, o resultado da divisão é a resposta
- se não for exata, soma 1 ao resultado da divisão

---

#### Mas ainda não é suficiente

**Se a diferença entre `a` e `b` for menor que 3**, o valor de `n` é igual a zero, então não dá para aplicar a regra acima, pois não temos como fazer `n - 1` incrementos de 3 (pois isso daria "-1 incrementos").

Então neste caso específico temos:

- se o resto for 1, teria que ser 2 incrementos (1 de 3 em `a` e 1 de 2 em `b`)
- se o resto for 2, teria que ser 1 incremento de 2 em `a`
- se o resto for zero, é porque `a` e `b` são iguais, então precisa de zero incrementos

Juntando tudo, ficaria assim:

```
# ler os valores de "a" e "b"...

qtd, resto = divmod(b - a, 3)
if resto != 0:
    if qtd == 0: # quando a diferença entre a e b é menor que 3
        qtd = 3 - resto
    else:
        qtd += 1
print(f'Foram necessários {qtd} movimentos')
```

---

E aproveitando, se você sabe que a entrada sempre terá 2 números na mesma linha e nada mais, pode lê-los assim:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

E se eles não necessariamente estiverem em ordem (por exemplo, se o `a` puder ser maior que o `b` na entrada), pode calcular a diferença usando [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), para que retorne o valor sem sinal:

```
qtd, resto = divmod(abs(b - a), 3)
```

Desta forma você não precisa se preocupar em criar uma lista com os números, para depois pegar o `max` e o `min`.

Ou ainda, como são apenas 2 números, bastaria invertê-los se o `a` for maior:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
qtd, resto = divmod(b - a, 3)
etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

> A solução apresentada nesta resposta não funciona para todas as situações.

> Não analisarei seu código, pois você compreendeu errado o problema e o código não reflete o que se pede no exercício.

Considerando que você possui os números A e B (B > A).

A cada "movimento" você pode decidir se deseja incrementar em 2 ou incrementar em 3 qualquer um dos números, até que fiquem numericamente iguais. Por exemplo, considerando que A=2 e B=13, precisamos sair de 2 até igualar a 13.

1. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=5;
2. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=8;
3. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=11;
4. Podemos adicionar 2 em A, obtendo A=13;

Portanto, foram necessários 4 "movimentos". Mas e se fosse A=2 e B=12?

1. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=5;
2. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=8;
3. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=11;
4. Podemos adicionar 2 em B, obtendo B=14;
5. Podemos adicionar 3 em A, obtendo A=14;

Sendo necessários, agora, 5 "movimentos".

A lógica se simplifica em:

- Enquanto a diferença B-A for maior ou igual a 3, incremente A em 3;
- Se a diferença B-A for igual a 2, incremente A em 2;
- Se a diferença B-A for igual a 1, incremente B em 2;

Em código, ficaria algo como:

```py
quantidade = 0

while (B-A > 0):
  quantidade += 1
  if B-A >= 3:
    A += 3
  elif B-A == 2:
    A += 2
  else:
    B += 2

print(f'Foram necessários {quantidade} movimentos')
```

Ou ainda:

```py
quantidade = 0

while (B-A >= 3):
  quantidade += 1
  A += 3

if B-A == 2:
  A += 2
  quantidade += 1
elif B-A == 1:
  B += 2
  A += 3
  quantidade += 2

print(f'Foram necessários {quantidade} movimentos')
```

Essa solução não é ideal, embora seja mais simples de entender, pois sua complexidade computacional é O(n), em que o número de operações realizadas será diretamente dependente da entrada. Para B >> A, haverá impacto em performance.

#### Matemática ❤️

Você não precisa de um laço de repetição para saber quantas vezes você irá incrementar em 3 o valor de A até ele se aproximar de B. A matemática já te diz isso em uma operação.

- Se o valor B-A for múltiplo de 3, você precisará (B-A)//3 movimentos - apenas incrementos de 3 em A;
- Se o resto da divisão de B-A por 3 for 2, você precisará (B-A)//3 + 1 movimentos - vários incrementos de 3 e um de 2 em A;
- Se o resto da divisão de B-A por 3 for 1, você precisará (B-A)//3 + 2 movimentos - vários incrementos de 3 em A, um incremento de 2 em A e um incremento de 2 em B;

> Entenda `//` como divisão inteira entre os operandos.

Portanto:

```py
quantidade = 0

if (B-A) % 3 == 0:
  quantidade = (B-A) // 3
elif (B-A) % 3 == 1:
  quantidade = (B-A) // 3 + 2
else:
  quantidade = (B-A) // 3 + 1

print(f'Foram necessários {quantidade} movimentos')
```

Essa solução é ideal, mesmo que inicialmente pareça mais complexa, pois sua complexidade computacional é O(1), realizando exatamente o mesmo número de operações, independente da entrada. O impacto em B >> A será o mesmo que quando B é muito próximo de A.

#### Matemática ❤️ v2.0.0

Graças a colaboração do [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) nos comentários lembrando da função `divmod`, é possível ainda fazer:

```py
A = 2
B = 13

div, mod = divmod(B-A, 3)

if mod == 2:
    mod = 1
elif mod == 1:
    mod = 2

print(f'Foram necessários {div+mod} movimentos')
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119107/discussion-on-answer-by-woss-calcular-quantidade-de-incrementos-para-que-2-numer)

Comment: muito obrigado @hkotsubo

Answer (score 1):

Só uma pequena reescrita (de gosto ofuscado e duvidoso) da versão @hkotsubo, no intuito de descomprimir dum trabalho chato que tenho que fazer...

```
a,b = sorted(map(int,input().split()))
q,r = divmod(b-a,3)
print( q + (r!=0) + (b-a==1))
```